# color key in heatmap.2 does not color

Tags: r, colors, heatmap

I ran heatmap.2 in R, and am not able to generate a colored color key to show the density of the plot in the upper left corner.

I am able to make the color key with the following:

```
library(gplots)
a=cbind(a=1:5000,b=1:5000*2,c=1:5000*4,d=1:5000*8,e=1:5000*16)
h=hclust(dist(log(t(a))))
d=as.dendrogram(h)
dd=reorder(d,c(-10,1,1,1,100))
hm=colorRampPalette(c('yellow','green','red'))(nrow(a)*ncol(a))
png(file="CompleteHeatmap.png",width=1200,height=800)
par(oma=c(1,1,1,5))
heatmap.2(log(a),scale='none',trace='none',col=hm,density.info='density',denscol='black',Colv=dd)
```

With this, the color key comes up fine and accurate. Yet when I run it with my actual data (39000 * 6 columns) I do not get a colored color key, although the density plot shown is accurate.

If anyone has any ideas why this might occur, I would like to hear, as my boss would like to have the color key colored correctly.

My data table is a little more than 7 times the size of the matrix made above, but other than that, all the calls are the same.

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: So what does your plot look like? If the code you've provided doesn't reproduce the same error, then it's impossible to know what you are seeing. Are you saying you have 6 columns with 39000 rows? Or are you saying you have 234000 columns? It's very unclear to me what your exact problem is.

Comment: I've also added the appropriate `library` call for `heatmap.2` to your question.  And If you're calling `png()`, I'm assuming you're also calling `dev.off()` at the end? If do, that should be in the sample; if not, that could be a problem.

Comment: I have 6 columns of 39000 rows, and have added the library call to gplots, as well as dev.off(). I found the processing time was quicker when I call png() as opposed to doing it on screen.

Comment: How can I add a png picture to show what I mean?

Comment: If you upload an PNG to a site like imgur.com, you can the provide the link in your question. Someone with higher rep can change the link to an inline image.

Comment: http://imgur.com/oEO9dzs is the image produced from the included code. http://imgur.com/53nB27E is my personal data. The coding and calls are identical, except for the reference matrix, but my data does not have a colored color key

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer, and altered the colorpallete with

```
hm=colorRampPalette(c('yellow','green','red'))(256)
```

in position of nrow()*ncol() and it worked out!

Comment: I had the same problem trying to specify a color scale with around 800 colors.  I think for most practical purposes 256 colors is enough so it's not a big issue.  Is this behavior documented in the `heatmap.2` help?